# What is the use of male plants in nature?

Tags: botany, pollination

If pollination is done by insects like bees and through the air, then what is the use of male plants in nature?

Comment: They are just the delivery service for [Pollen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pollen, spermatozoid, ovules and bees**

The pollen is a coarse substance containing the spermatozoids. Males plant creates these pollens. As bees visit the flowers, the pollen get stuck on their body. When the bee covered with pollen visits female plant, then the pollen may randomly stick onto the female organ. The spermatozoid grow into a tube within this organ and goes to fertilize the ovule.

**In short, bees are ...**

In other words, you need females for the ovaries, males for the spermatozoids and bees for the delivery services.

Note that bees don't do this delivery services just to be nice with plants. They do so because they get nectar (substance full of sugar) in the flowers.

**Reality is more complex and more diverse**

Note also, that reality is more complex and more diverse than what I explained. Not all plant species are pollinated by bees. Not all plant species have flowers. Most plant species are hermaphrodite (have male and female flowers or even have male and female organ within the same flower).